# Tail stops tailing logs in pod sidecar

Tags: kubernetes, tail

I have a pod running in kubernetes with some sidecars tailing different log files from the "master" container with following command:

```
tail -n+1 -f path/to/log.file
```

The problem is that, some days after deployed the pod, one of the sidecars stops tailing logs, while the rest of them continue to work normally.

The one that fails is always the same, tailing a bigger log file compared to the others.

I went into the sidecar and tailed manually and then I could see the logs normally.

The pod didn't restart and the log file was not recreated at the time the tailing stopped. The only think I can see is that the pod released some memory some minutes earlier, but I don't know how this could be related to the issue.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Is any sort of log rotation happening with the file in question?

Comment: @kristaps yes, there is log rotation for this file, happens ~4 times a day. Could it be because of this? When I said the file was not recreated I meant by me, it could be recreated because of the rotation, but I can't see when this happened as I can have log files only up to 2 days ago and this happened earlier.

Comment: @kristaps the other log files which are tailed correctly have rotation as well.

Comment: Tail has the ``--max-unchanged-stats=N`` flag, that reopens a file after ``N`` iterations, if the file size has not changed to check if it has been unlinked, which can happen on log rotation.

Comment: Is the rotation time or file size based? If you say that the bigger file is causing problems then maybe it's rotated earlier due reaching some size limit earlier?

Comment: @katerina, any progress on your problem?

Comment: yes @kristaps it seems it was clearly an issue due to recreation of the log file. what I don't know is why we could observe it only in this case and not in the rest of the files. will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to recreation of the log file.
the issue seems to be solved after replacing -f with -F.

```
tail -n+1 -F path/to/log.file
```

Still not sure why in the other cases with log rotation there was no problem, but anyway this should not be an issue from now on